# Json formation Getting corrupted

Tags: android, android-json

I am using JSONObject to create a new json in my Android Application. 
But I am experiencing a strange issue where I am observing that my json field names are getting replaced by letters like "a" : "value " , "b " : "value_1" , "c" : value2 " 
This works fine for smaller number of childs but as the number grows it distorts the json :

example json :

```
{
"Employees" : [
{
"userId":"rirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Romin",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
"employeeCode":"E1",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
"emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
},
{
"userId":"nirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Neil",
"lastName":"Irani",
"preferredFullName":"Neil Irani",
"employeeCode":"E2",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1111111",
"emailAddress":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
},
{
"userId":"thanks",
"jobTitleName":"Program Directory",
"firstName":"Tom",
"lastName":"Hanks",
"preferredFullName":"Tom Hanks",
"employeeCode":"E3",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-2222222",
"emailAddress":"tomhanks@gmail.com"
}
]
}
```

Corrupted output :

```
{
"Employees" : [
{
"a":"rirani",
"b":"Developer",
"c":"Romin",
"d":"Irani",
"e":"Romin Irani",
"f":"E1",
"g":"CA",
"h":"408-1234567",
"i":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
},
{
"a":"nirani",
"b":"Developer",
"c":"Neil",
"d":"Irani",
"e":"Neil Irani",
"f":"E2",
"g":"CA",
"h":"408-1111111",
"i":"neilrirani@gmail.com"
},
{
"a":"thanks",
"b":"Program Directory",
"c":"Tom",
"d":"Hanks",
"e":"Tom Hanks",
"f":"E3",
"g":"CA",
"h":"408-2222222",
"i":"tomhanks@gmail.com"
}
]
}
```

Is this a bug in the Android JSON object ? Any hints?

Comment: You need to show us the code which is causing this to happen.

Comment: Show us the code from which you are generating JSON...

Comment: there is probably something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue based on proguard rules in app level gradle file to that value make false like below ..

```
    minifyEnabled false
```

other wise you can add key in your pojo class like

```
    @SerializedName("userId") // pass your json key
private String userId;
```

Comment: interesting , if it works , you have saved our lives !! Trying it out !